# Is there any way to create a variable in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know that there is no direct way to create a variable in Minecraft but is there any way to manipulate scoreboard objectives into creating one?

Basically, I need to create a variable that will store a players X Y Z when they reach less than 10 health. 
The name of the "Health" objective is  "down".

I'm not sure how to make this question less like a demand. I'm not sure where to start on this but the main thing that I am "Capable" of is looking online for other questions. The only thing that has come up are people asking for this to be added, but someone in a forum mentioned scoreboard objectives being able to do the trick.

**EDIT**

So I don't beleive I was clear enough: I need this to store the players location data **live**. As in a repeating command block test's for a player with less than ten health and then stores the players current location which I can then use later to teleport the player to the saved coordinates. E.g

```
/testfor @a[score_down=10] {Coordinated:[{X(var X) = 1,Y(var Y) = 2,Z(var Z) = 3}]}
```

Basicall y ^ that works like Coordinated < Position Tag, X < X position tag, var < declared that the output will be the variable.

THAT IS IMPOSSIBLE ^

But I hope you catch my drift by the way I explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that there was an alternative way to do what I needed to do and this did not involve creating a variable. The reason I wanted to know the player's location live was so I could freeze them on the spot. Instead, I used this:

```
/execute @a[score_down=10] ~ ~ ~ /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b,Small:1b}

/tp @a[score_down=10] @e[type=ArmorStand]
```

You can, of course, give the ArmorStand a custom name to reduce glitchiness but I did not need it.

Answer (score -1):

today I was searching how to make a variables and I found, that closest thing to variables is a /scoreboard objectives add score dummy "score"

edit: score is a name of the variable

Comment: Could you expand on this with a short example of how it' used? Thanks!

Comment: /scoreboard objectives add score dummy "score"

/gamerule commandBlockOutput false

and place 1 minecraft:repeating_command_block and after that 2 minecraft:chain_command_block and put this command in a 

first command block(that repeating one): /execute at kudy_zero if block ~ ~-1 ~ grass_block run scoreboard players set kudy_zero score 1 

second block: /execute at kudy_zero if score kudy_zero score matches 1 run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:quartz_block replace 

third /execute at kudy_zero run scoreboard players reset kudy_zero score

Comment: My comment was too long so I shortened it only to the commands, first command will make a variable named score, second command will provent you from getting spammed in a chat by command blocks, and last three commands that you will put in a powered command blocks will do that every time you step on a grass block it will give you score 1 and if you have a score it will replace it with a quartz block.

Comment: And my minecraft nick is a kudy_zero so if you copy those commands and paste them in your command blocks it won't work, beacuse it is on my name, you must delete kudy_zero and type your name.

Comment: And I wrote them in a version 1.14.4. and in a second commnet i meant "if you have a score 1 it will replace it with a quartq block"

Comment: Thanks Kudy! That example is  really hard to read in comments. Would you mind editing that information into your answer? I'd do it myself, but I don't have a lot of experience with Minecraft commands, so I don't think I'd be able to get it quite right.

Comment: /scoreboard objectives add score dummy "score"

Comment: /gamerule commandBlockOutput false

Comment: /execute at [your name] if block ~ ~-1 ~ grass_block run scoreboard players set [your name] score 1

Comment: /execute at [your name] if score [your name] score matches 1 run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:quartz_block replace

Comment: /execute at [your name] run scoreboard players reset [your name] score

Answer (score -1):

```
/scoreboard objectives add score dummy "score"  

/gamerule commandBlockOutput false 

/execute at [your name] if block ~ ~-1 ~ grass_block run scoreboard players set [your name] score 1

/execute at [your name] if score [your name] score matches 1 run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:quartz_block replace  

/execute at [your name] run scoreboard players reset [your name] score
```

Comment: Care to explain how the syntax works?

Comment: I explained it in my previous answer to Wipqozn. It will basically put a quartzblock under you when you stand on a grassblock.